# Compiler says to add type parameters, but I don't think I can in this context

Tags: rust

The compiler complains that type annotations are needed. I was able to fix it by creating an unused variable with type parameters, commented out in the code snippet below. This feels like a weird workaround though, is there some way to add type parameters without needing to do this? It just seems like rust should know the type of `key` because `Map` is a defined type.

```
type Map = Arc<DashMap<[u8; 32], Session>>;

pub struct SessionManager {
    map: Map,
    db_wtx: WriteTx,
    db_rtx: ReadTx,
}

impl SessionManager{
    pub fn logout(&self, token: &str) {
        if let Ok(decoded_vec) = base64::decode(token) {
            if let Ok(key) = decoded_vec.try_into() {
                //let _typed_key: [u8; 32] = key;
                self.map.remove(&key);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error msg:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
   --> src/login_handler.rs:244:14
    |
244 |             if let Ok(key) = decoded_vec.try_into() {
    |                       ^^^    ---------------------- this method call resolves to `Result<T, <Self as TryInto<T>>::Error>`
    |                       |
    |                       cannot infer type
```

edit: for clarity I'm using the dashmap crate, which tries to mimic the api of std::hashmap closely while allowing multithreaded access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rustc can't infer the type because [`Map::remove()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.remove) (assuming you're actually talking about `HashMap`, or `BTreeMap`) doesn't take `&K` as the parameter type (where `K` is the key type), but rather some `Q` where `Q: Borrow<K>`. This allows for more flexibility (for example, passing a `&str` for a map of `String`s), but come at the cost of worse inference.

There are few alternatives: You can specify the type for the `Ok`:

```rust
if let Ok::<[u8; 32], _>(key) = decoded_vec.try_into()
```

This is a shorthand for:

```rust
if let Result::<[u8; 32], _>::Ok(key) = decoded_vec.try_into()
```

Or you can use `TryFrom` instead of `TryInto`:

```rust
if let Ok(key) = <[u8; 32]>::try_from(decoded_vec)
```

If you choose a variable, note that it is preferred to use `_` and not another underscore-prefixed name like `_typed_key`. This is because `_` does not move the value, but any other name does. This is not relevant in this case since `[u8; 32]` is `Copy`, but still a good practice.

Comment: Ah, that is helpful, thanks! a correction: it appears `Ok` requires two type parameters, even if the err variant isn't used (i.e. Ok::<[u8;32], _>). Still though, got me in the right direction!